# Right click won't bring up the Object Context Menu

Tags: modeling, mesh

I just started using blender and am doing the new version of the famous donut tutorial. One problem, when I right click the donut in object mode, the object context menu doesn't appear, anyone know what's up?

[image]

Comment: In Preferences>Keymap you have to select simple "Blender" preset and Left Click for "Select With".

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue. I had to go on my mac settings for the mouse under preferences and activate: **Secondary click** -> **click on the right side**.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the right click select, then you can hit the W key, for the object context menu. Or if you'd like to use Left click select, you can click on edit, and then click on Preferences. Then under Keymap, change the, Select with mouse button, to Left. Then save the user preferences.

Answer (score 0):

Just watch out if you're in *Edit Mode* or not (<kbd>Tab</kbd>). If you are in the *Edit Mode*, just go back to the view object and now select your object and right click outside the object.

Answer (score 0):

Hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> to *Edit Mode* and you can right click the armature context menu